# store form data along with image in database

Tags: php, json, api

Its my first API, in this i am able to store id,name, description, price, category_id in my abc table of xyz database. I just want to store the image_id, image_name, image_url also in the same table. I also want, that image will store in my upload directory. Below,in my code I am able to store id,name, description, price, category_id in my table. I am using POSTMAN for this. Can anyone help me out.....

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// get database connection
include_once '../config/database.php';

// instantiate product object
include_once '../objects/product.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$product = new Product($db);

// get posted data
$data = (object) $_POST;

// set product property values
$product->name = $data->name;
$product->price = $data->price;
$product->description = $data->description;
$product->category_id = $data->category_id;
$product->created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// create the product
if($product->create()){
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Product was created."';
    echo '}';
}

// if unable to create the product, tell the user
else{
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Unable to create product."';
    echo '}';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/upload%20image%20to%20database%20and%20server%20using%20HTML,PHP%20and%20MySQL.php

This is a best solution.
Copy the code AND try

if u want to upload in folder,
here you go.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: You never want to store images in databases. If you store a lot of images, the database would get really slow. In my opinion, upload the image to the server. Save them there, and get the name.extension of the image and store that in the Database.

Comment: i agree but he wanted in database, so he can, if he want to store in folder also he can store.

Comment: It's just an observation and a tip. You should add that into your answer. Otherwise OP might get the wrong idea about image saving and databases :)

Comment: I have already done these in php with UI of HTML, but when i am trying this through POSTMAN, it shows errors..

Comment: send screen shoot

Comment: send your images